# Preserve $_POST variables through different pages like $_SESSION

Tags: php, variables, post

Once some data are submitted through POST, is it possible to make them available as $_POST through different pages, same like how $_SESSION allows us to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Digging up an old question today. But i forgot to post the working solution I dug....

Place this snippet in top of your every page

```
if(isset($_POST) & count($_POST)) { $_SESSION['post'] = $_POST; }
if(isset($_SESSION['post']) && count($_SESSION['post'])) { $_POST = $_SESSION['post']; }
```

Comment: Yikes! Write-only coding at its finest.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to parse the data in $_POST and recreate it in your form. You can do it with hidden fields.

Or, you can save the $_POST data in a user session and refer to it when you need it. You'll have to manage the lifecycle of the data to make sure it doesn't stay around too long.

Comment: I am sending the query string using links, so i am not using form to post those

Comment: Then you'll have to parse $_POST into parameters and add them to your link. They'll be available to your script in $_GET and $_REQUEST.

Comment: the cure is even worst than the disease. what if there are large text or some sensitive information like password?

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: I believe I've answered with the only options: parse the array and repost it, or use a session. As you can see, the OP has not given us enough information to comment on the best method for his circumstances - though it looks to me like a complete redesign and rewrite is in order.

Comment: @scott, I am using the exact way you are saying... and as @Col. Shrapnel said, posting these values in url will leave the system vulnerable to injection..... That's why I was wondering if there was a way :( to do this

Comment: Injection is not the problem he was talking about. Injection is just as possible with POSTed forms. The problem with adding stuff to the URL is the max length of the URL is shorter than what you can POST and all of your data is visible to users who 'view source' (which is also a problem with rePOSTing from a form). Either way, your three options have been outlined in a number of answers: resubmit the data, use a session, or redesign your application. There is no other way.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are sending the data in via the URL which is stored in the $_GET variable, not in $_POST.  If you want the ability to submit the data in either format, use $_REQUEST instead.

There is a bit of a debate on whether it is a good idea to use $_REQUEST, but if you are doing a simple site, there is little wrong with it.

If you would rather not use $_REQUEST, then you can use the following code on each variable you are expecting:

```
if (!empty($_GET['foo'])) {
    $foo = $_GET['foo'];
} elseif (!empty($_POST['foo'])) {
    $foo = $_POST['foo'];
} else {
    die("Foo not submitted");
}
```